# Initialize list with variable number of the same value

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to initialize a list x times with the value of y?

Thus instead of:

```
mutableListOf(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

something like:

```
makeMutableList(4, 0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just like this:

```
MutableList(4) { 0 }
```

This calls the factory function [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list.html) which takes a size and a lambda, passing to the lambda the index and setting the appropriate element to the result of the lambda. Thus, to create the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` you can do this:

```
MutableList(4) { it + 1 }
```

If you don't need a *mutable* list, there is also a [List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list.html) factory function.

When running on the JVM, both `List` and `MutableList` functions create a `java.util.ArrayList`, though you shouldn't rely on the exact type.